# Exponent of a summation

Tags: python, math

I am a very new python user.
I am trying to calculate an exponent of a summation.  The array has more parameters.

```
import math

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]

def y(i):
    p = 2
    total = 0
    for j in range (4):
        total += math.exp(a[i][j] * (p**j))

    return total
```

Answer from this method:  `7.89629603455e+13`

The answer is way different than manual calculation below:

```
y = math.exp(1*(2**0) + 2*(2**1) + 3*(2**2) + 4*(2**3))
```

Answer: `1.9073465725e+21`

[image: Equation]

Comment: Can you post expected answer for this

Comment: The expected output has the sum *inside* the exponential, while in the loop you take the exponential first and then sum. These aren't the same.

Comment: @RBalasubramanian, I put the correct indentation in Python.  When I copy and paste, it changes.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but I think you have a mistake.. `exp(x+y) != exp(x) + exp(y)` - perhaps change to `total *= ...`

Comment: @MohammadAthar, I was playing around with different methods, I put the correct code.  Please ignore the indentation.

Comment: Note that the mathematical formula reads: "sum the products of each `a` and `p` **then** take `e` to the power of that sum". This is not what your original code implements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake appears to not be a python error, but a math error in decomposing the equation. You can make one of two changes:

**Solution 1: Sum all first, then take e^ of the total**

```
import math

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]

def y(i):
    p = 2
    total = 0
    for j in range (4):
        total += a[i][j] * (p**j)

    return math.exp(total)
```

**Solution 2: correctly decompose the exponent and change total += to total *=**

```
import math

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]

def y(i):
    p = 2
    total = 0
    for j in range (4):
        total *= math.exp(a[i][j] * (p**j))

    return total
```

Solution 1 is more efficient, as it does not make duplicate calls to math.exp()

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]

def y(i):
    p = 2
    total = 1
    for j in range (4):
        total *= math.exp(a[i][j] * (p**j))
    return total
```

Multiplication of exponentianals with same base is same with summing the power values.

```
exp(a+b)=exp(a)*exp(b)
```

Optimization of the code:

```
import math

a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]

def y(i):
    p = 2
    total = 0
    for j in range (4):
        total += a[i][j] * (p**j)
    return math.exp(total)
```

Comment: Much better to simply compute the sum, then pass that as the argument to a *single* call to `math.exp`.

Comment: @chepner you are right but he is starter so i wrote first code because it is easier to find the false.

Comment: Note that the "optimized" code implements the mathematical formula directly.